# turtlebot_marker error in RViz

Tags: rviz, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have followed every bit of instruction on:

> http://ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_interactive_markers/Tutorials/UsingTurtlebotInteractiveMarkers

When the RViz GUI pops up everything looks fine and dandy until I go to turtlebot_marker where it states this:

> turtlebot_marker
> Error getting time of latest transform between /base_link
> and /odom: (error code: 1)

What does that mean and how can I fix it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30521/turtlebot_marker-error-in-rviz./) by [njavia66](https://answers.ros.org/users/1906/njavia66/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2012-03-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2012-03-26**:
what nodes are running on the TurtleBot and what version of the TurtleBot software are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had same problem.

I solved this problem..

Choose the '/base_link' of Fixed Frame in Global Options..

---

Originally posted by [SanghaNam](https://answers.ros.org/users/2025/sanghanam/) with karma: 54 on 2012-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3